# quit while loop inside for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, exit

I have the following logic in my code:

```
count=0

for x in lst:
    print('hello!')

    while True:
        rep=input('save this?y/n?')
        print(rep)

        if rep=="y":
            print('wow amazing')
            count=count+1
            break

        elif rep=="n":
            print('moving to next target')
            count=count+1
            break

            
        else:
            print('please enter either y/n')


print('DONE!')
```

I want to add a condition that `if rep=="quit"`, the code will stop running (also stop the for loop not only the while loop). currently, break just stop the current while loop but not the whole for loop. how can I quit the whole for loop base don value inserted in the while loop?

Comment: Easy way would be to put it in a function and let it `return`

Comment: Or you add a variable, put it true if breaks and then break after the while if the variable is true and set it back to False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit_loop`: variable helps to make the decision when to quit the outer loop

```
count=0
exit_loop = False
for x in lst:
    print('hello!')
    while True:
        rep=input('save this?y/n?')
        print(rep)
        if rep=="y":
            print('wow amazing')
            count=count+1
            break
        elif rep=="n":
            print('moving to next target')
            count=count+1
            break
        elif rep=="quit":
            print("Quitting")
            exit_loop = True
            break    
        else:
            print('please enter either y/n')
    if exit_loop:
        break

print('DONE!')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to exit both loops, you can simply just create a flag to do the check in both loops:

```
count = 0
should_break = False
for x in lst:
    print('hello!')

    while True:
        rep=input('save this?y/n?')
        print(rep)

        if rep == "y":
            print('wow amazing')
            count = count + 1
            break

        elif rep == "n":
            print('moving to next target')
            count = count + 1
            break

        elif rep == "q":
            should_break = True
            break
            
        else:
            print('please enter either y/n')

    if should_break:
        break

print('DONE!')
```

If you're trying to exit your program completely, you may do the following:

```
if rep=='q':
    exit()
```